# JavaScript callback using promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have worked with this for about 2 hours now. I have searched SO as well as other resources and can't find an answer that will work in my situation. This is my first time using callbacks and so it may be simple, but I can't see the issue.
With the following snippet, I keep getting an error that says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

Here is the function in which I am getting the error.

```
getTemplateName: function() {
    this.openDialog({ 
        height: 150, 
        width: 300, 
        position: ["center", 80],   
        closeOnEscape: true, 
        modal:true
    }, "templateName.html");
    var templateName = $("#templateName").val();
    templateName.then(function(){
        alert(templateName);
    });
    return templateName;
}
```

Somehow, I am missing it. I can't find what the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... You're calling `.then` on `templateName`, which is the value of an element, which is a string...

Comment: `templateName` is a string, it has no `then`

Comment: What is the purpose of using a promise here? You'd have better to describe your expected behaviour instead

Comment: It sounds like you are conflating two concepts, [promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) and [callbacks](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: also where is the which plugin are you using to open the dialog?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do a bit more so that people can help you? I see that you are getting an error and it is easy to get rid of that error but what is your end goal of this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't decide to use promises where none exist.

The dialog library you're using accepts a `complete` callback, and that's what you need to use. You need to fundamentally change the way your code works. Your `getTemplate` method cannot return a value if that value comes from an event that will happen some time in the future, such as a user dismissing a dialog. Instead, it must accept a callback which gets passed the value at some point in the future:

```
getTemplateName: function(callback) {
    this.openDialog({ 
        height: 150, 
        width: 300, 
        position: ["center", 80],   
        closeOnEscape: true, 
        modal:true,
        close: function () {
          callback($("#templateName").val());
        }
    }, "templateName.html");

}
```

Comment: @meager So, if I am following you, then I will need to use something like this? (Just found this fiddle). http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/jcmpm/

Comment: @meager.... That still doesn't quite do it. For whatever reason, the code continues to run prior to the user entering a value into the dialog box and then the "template" saves to the db without a user-defined name.

Comment: Yes, the code *will* continue to run. That is why you need to use a callback function. Whatever code you're saving to the database needs to be executed by the callback passed into `getTemplateName`.

Comment: Ok.... I think I see that, but now, I get an error in JS console that says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" in reference to semi-colon behind callback( $("#tempName").val() ... Any thoughts? I don't understand that at all as it has to have a semi-colon.

Comment: @meager just to see what would happen, I removed the semi-colon and now get an error telling me that the close function is undefined....

Comment: @meager correction... Telling me that  undefined is not a function..... Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function openDialog.closejquery-ui.js:9 a.Widget._triggerjquery-ui.js:53 a.widget.close

Comment: Just realized this particular website uses a very old version of jQuery which is why the code you gave me was not working @meager. I referenced the CDN at google for the current version and it works. So, I am accepting your answer. Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

`then` and associated functions such as `done` and `fail` only work when a function returns a `promise`. `val()` returns a plain old string which does not have a `then` method as the error alludes to.

You just need to remove the `then` reference completely:

```
getTemplateName: function() {
    this.openDialog({ 
        height: 150, 
        width: 300, 
        position: ["center", 80],   
        closeOnEscape: true, 
        modal:true
    }, "templateName.html");
    var templateName = $("#templateName").val();
    alert(templateName);
    return templateName;
}
```

Comment: Ok.... The thing is I need the code to wait while the dialog is processed. Sort of like a JS prompt would do... But in searching, the only method that I could find that would come close to what I need is using the promise with the then... Does that make sense?

Comment: @trouble706 Doesn't this `openDialog` plugin expose a close event? If ya, use it to set logic there

Comment: @A.Wolff. It does. It is simply the jQuery dialog widget... But what I need is for the code to wait on the user to enter a value in the dialog box like a javascript prompt and then the code resume running so to speak.. I can't find any way to make that happen with the dialog so I was trying the then... But I guess that is not going to do it for me either then, huh?

Comment: @trouble706 You cannot simply replicate modal native behaviour of javascript using anything else than specific methods as prompt or alert. But still, i don't get why don't you use the relevant callback instead?!

Comment: @A.Wolff As I commented below to meager. I found this fiddle a few minutes ago. http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/jcmpm/ Is that what you are referring to? I wasn't aware that it existed and so that is why I wasn't using it.. But looking at implementing it now..

Comment: @trouble706 Ya, but in jsFiddle, the `promise().done()` is to handle animation queue. If you aren't using any animation, you don't need it. But the `close` callback is what you need

Comment: @A.Wolff ... That doesn't work. It still allows the code to run rather than waiting on the user's input into the dialog. In this case, what that means is that the "template" gets saved before it is ever named...

Comment: @trouble706 You should update jsFiddle to replicate your issue so it could be checked. I'm not sure what means `the "template" gets saved before it is ever named`?!

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of jquery's deferred objects here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Basically, any of jQuery's ajax methods will return an object, that has promise-related methods like `done`, `fail`, `when` and `then`. These are replacements for the old `success` and `error` callbacks.

A simple example might look like this:

```
var promise = $.ajax(url, ....);
promise.done(function(response) {
    console.log("response was a success");
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a `promise`, not a `deferred`. Renaming your `var` will do :)

Comment: Thanks! I renamed the var per your suggestion.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Either I am not following you or that is not working. I tried renaming as well as casting to obj. And can't make it work with either method.